# Font from SVGs based on Unicode

Tags: fonts, font-design, glyphs

is it possible to create a font if we have all the Unicode characters for the language available in individual SVGs ?

I tried using IcoMoon but the output was not as I intended. The top font is the original and the bottom one is the dotted font derived from it. As you can see the `joint` letters are detached and even normal letters retain the space which the SVG had.

Unicode details about the characters - https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0D00.pdf

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest one, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Font creation/editing software is *specifically* designed to take glyphs, in vector form and generate working font files. Allowing the creator to set options such as default letter spacing, tracking, etc.

If your SVG glyphs are vector, all you need do is use *actual* font creation software, not "icon collection" software.

CreativeBloq has an article [**HERE**](https://www.creativebloq.com/typography/best-font-editors-21619292) which reviews several font creation/editing applications.

Comment: Thanks. I have all of the symbols as Inkscape SVG ( I can make them Plain SVG). It would be nice to know whether any of those software supports dotted fonts, which are a collection of dots under `union`. I do not see any mention of such types of fonts in the blog post.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they will all support "dingbat" fonts.. which are more art than latin type character.

Comment: Would it possible to find a free option ? I am not a font designer, this a simple community contribution. It would be crazy to invest such a big amount. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've tried to help.. but I'm not a "personal shopper". It's kind of up to you to sort through products to find one which fits your needs. Even products which cost money often offer a free trial.